# Object cannot be stored in an array of this type. issue in MVC c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am facing below issue on production application and not able to found any specific location or code as a cause of the error can anyone having any idea then please suggest a solution.

```
message="Object cannot be stored in an array of this type."    
source="mscorlib"    
detail="System.InvalidCastException: Object cannot be stored in an array of this type.&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Array.InternalSetValue(Void* target, Object value)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Array.SetValue(Object value, Int32[] indices)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.CompleteObject(ObjectHolder holder, Boolean bObjectFullyComplete)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoNewlyRegisteredObjectFixups(ObjectHolder holder)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.RegisterObject(Object obj, Int64 objectID, SerializationInfo info, Int64 idOfContainingObj, MemberInfo member, Int32[] arrayIndex)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.RegisterObject(Object obj, ParseRecord pr, ParseRecord objectPr, Boolean bIsString)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ParseObjectEnd(ParseRecord pr)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader reader)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String name, Boolean check)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String name)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.HttpSessionStateWrapper.get_Item(String name)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.SessionStateTempDataProvider.LoadTempData(ControllerContext controllerContext)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Load(ControllerContext controllerContext, ITempDataProvider tempDataProvider)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.PossiblyLoadTempData()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;BeginProcessRequest&gt;b__20_0(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback callback, Object callbackState)&#xD;&#xA;   

at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)&#xD;&#xA;   
at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean&amp; completedSynchronously)"    user="extranet\0031O00003QP1nTQAT"    
time="2020-06-10T13:54:03.7681729Z">
```

Comment: Looks like you are getting some unexpected input that is tryied to be put into the TempData of a contoller. You can propably search for places where some input is put into TempData. Should look something like TempData["SomeKey"]  = someValue

Answer (score 0):

I know its late, but I am curious if there was any development on this.

The "System.Web.Mvc.TempDataDictionary.Load" in the error definitely gives the clue that, this is something do with data stored in TempData. I also experienced the problem, but I could not exactly identify what data created the problem, because the code was abusing temp data a lot. Good news is that, I removed the code that uses TempData to store complex types. Its been 30 days and the exception is not happening again. Voila..!

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/28159

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into this direction as well.

Comment: Great. For me it is 10 months now, exception never happened. However, I still do not know what type of data is causing a problem, I am sure it is some complex data, not any builtin types. Good luck for you.